# Refused to load plugin data from 'data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJ**. Unable to set content security policy

Tags: html, vue.js, pdf, vuejs3, content-security-policy

I am setting content security policy as
`<meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="content-security-policy" content="object-src 'self' data:" />` and it render as
[image]

I am trying to render a base64 encode pdf using object tag in vue3 as shown

```
<object
      class="pdfObject"
      :data="'data:application/pdf;base64,' + props.encodedPdf"
      type="application/pdf"
    ></object>
```

and getting the below error
[image]

Comment: Content of image 1  <meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="content-security-policy" content="object-src 'self' data:">

Comment: Content of image2
 Refused to load plugin data from 'data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJfbk***==' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "object-src 'none'".

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that two policies are served. The other one is most likely found in a response header and sets the directive "object-src 'none';". Content needs to pass all policies, and if another policy allows nothing you'll need to remove or modify that policy first.

Answer (score 0):

I was using I3 service for authentication and CSP headers 'object-src' was set from their end. I had to update the header there.